# Add additional port to already active TCP Server?

Tags: delphi, tcp, delphi-7

How can I add additional port to an already active TCPserver ? (if possible)

something like,

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin    
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := 5555;
  IdTCPServer1.Active := not IdTCPServer1.Active
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //IdTCPServer1.Active := false;
  //IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := strtoint(Edit1.Text); //so here i want to add additional port
  //IdTCPServer1.Active := true;
end;
```

Comment: Deactivate the server, add the port to be listened and activate the server again.

Comment: Actually, you can **add** new ports without deactivating first.  But you cannot **remove** ports without deactivating.

Answer (score 1):

You can **add** a new port without deactivating the server first.  Simply `Add()` the new port to the `TIdTCPServer.Bindings` collection and then call `TIdTCPServer.StartListening()`.  Any Bindings that are not already running will start running:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin    
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := 5555;
  IdTCPServer1.Active := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  NewPort: TIdPort;
  I: Integer;
  Found: Boolean;
begin
  I := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  if (I < 1) or (I > 65535) then
    raise Exception.Create('Port value is not valid');

  NewPort := TIdPort(I);
  Found := False;

  for I := 0 to IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Count-1 do
  begin
    if IdTCPServer1.Bindings[I].Port = NewPort then
    begin
      Found := True;
      Break;
    end;
  end;

  if not Found then
    IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := NewPort;

  IdTCPServer1.StartListening;
end;
```

However, at this time, you cannot **remove** any ports while the server is active.  You must deactivate the server first.